# Add text in c# forms WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to a WPF project in c# and I want in my MainWindow interface to add a textbox. I use toolbox to add textBox field and with view code I found the following function:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

How can I change the default value of the textBox? The only thing the is generated when I add the Textbox was this function. Which variable is responsible for the text? EDIT: I am trying to modify a WPF application which is provided with the kinect SDK. It seems that is not that straight-forward. When I tried to right click on the textBox I cant see any properties option. Inside MainWIndow.xaml.cs there is a line with the property of the textbox:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="540,3,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
```

However I cant find the name of the textbox anywhere.

Comment: To get or change the text you should use the Text property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select the textbox and press F4 to access the selected item's properties (normally displayed in the bottom right of the screen), you can set the `Text` property in the property grid. The value you enter will be used when the form is first created.
This is equivalent to setting the `Text` XAML attribute on the `TextBox` element.

In code, you can also do this in your constructor using `textbox1.Text = "hello";` for instance.

Note, to access the `TextBox` in code you will need to assign it a name (also via the properties grid).

---

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox1" Text="Default Value Goes Here" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="540,3,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
```

Comment: My problem is that where should I look for the generated textbox object.

Comment: If you go to the form designer, you should have the XAML code below inside which you will find a line like `<TextBox ... />`

Comment: Yes I have already posted this line in the post.

Comment: Ok. I see that! You need to add an `x:Name` attribute ... i'll update my answer.

Comment: I've also added the default value bit for you!

Comment: I got textbox1 is a field but is used like a type error message.

Comment: What is the line of code that gives that error? `textbox1.Text="hello";` should work fine. NOTE: `TextBox` is a type, `textbox1` is an instance of a `TextBox` type.

Comment: Exactly textbox1.Text = "hello";

Comment: Well that sounds like you also have a field `textbox1` defined somewhere. Try changing `x:Name="MyTextbox"` and `MyTextbox.Text="hello";`

Comment: Now I am getting NullReferenceException.

Comment: Really sorry, but I haven't got time to debug all your errors! `NullReference` implies that `MyTextBox` has not been assigned anything. This could be because you are accessing it before `InitialiseComponent` has run. Otherwise, you need to post your full code under a different question. Sorry I can't be more help.

Answer (score 0):

The `Text` property is what holds the value of the textbox.

```
Textbox1.Text = " ";
```